# wkhtmltopdf get/post command

Tags: post, get, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to get wkhtmltopdf to take a screenshot of http://www.health.ny.gov/professionals/doctors/conduct/license_lookup.htm with the field search for license "lastname,first". Below is what I am currently sending in command line and is not working.

wkhtmltopdf -n post http://www.nysed.gov/COMS/OP001/OPSCR1 lastname,first screenshot.pdf

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get a PDF out of the search results page, the following command works using the latest version at the time of posting (wkhtmltopdf 0.11.0 rc2):

```
wkhtmltopdf --post profcd 60 --post pname smith http://www.nysed.gov/COMS/OP001/OPSCR1 out.pdf
```

You can check the version with `wkhtmltopdf -V`.

You need the profcd to as the backed seems to require it for the searches to work, otherwise you get something like "must select Profession".

Is that what you meant? Or did you want a PDF of the search page itself with the form inputs filled with your values? That will require some trickery I don't think it's impossible.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, and ironically I'm using the very same website.